# systemd's implementation of DNS is not resolving names

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, systemd

I have my own DNS server, DHCP sets it in any host on the LAN.

I have just installed a new Ubuntu 17.10 laptop

This command

```
nslookup abox
```

Can't find the IP of abox (it is in DNS)

```
nslookup
> server 192.168.1.30
abox
```

Returns the correct address

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

claims to be using

```
DNS Servers: 192.168.1.30
```

But it obviously is not, its using *127.0.0.53*, I can see the traffic in tcpdump.

So how do I tell systemd to stop messing with the DNS config that DHCP has told it to use and to actually start using the DNS server it claims to be using?

Comment: You could try disabling `dnsmasq` by commenting it out in the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

This post has [an answer.](https://osdocs.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/ubuntu-17-04-and-yet-another-round-of-i-fucked-up-your-resolv-conf-for-you-while-you-were-expecting-an-improved-distro/)

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
reboot
```

Now I can resolve DNS properly again.